# Google my business api Upload from bytes using php curl

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

I have this php curl function to upload the media bytes, but I don't know how to pass the file data.

```
public function mediaUpload($accessToken, $googleProvidedValue, $mediaByte) {
    $data = array(curl_file_create($mediaByte));

    $curl = curl_init('https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/upload/v1/media/'.$googleProvidedValue.'?upload_type=media');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    print_r($response);

}
```

The function prints null. How can I pass the file data to the curl?

Comment: You only need to pass the path to the file itself, curl takes care of the rest for you. Examples are provided under the [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) class documentation.

Comment: How I exactly pass to google my business media upload? I tried this `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(new \CURLFile($mediaByte)));` but doesn't work.  It gives this error `Fetching image failed.`

Comment: @JSN have you found a solution for this? I don't use php, but I get the same error using basic curl commands

Comment: @gybandi, not yet. I just used the Upload from a URL method for now.
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/upload-photos#upload-from-url

Comment: @JSN thanks, If I can't get the byte upload to work, I'll use that too

Comment: Let me know if you got the byte upload. Thanks! @gybandi

Comment: @codeblooded-saiyan on jul 28, I've got a response from the API support team, they created an issue for this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293595949